# How to edit admin TinyMCE JavaScript code (without modifying core files)?

Tags: admin, adminhtml, wysiwyg, tinymce

I'm looking to change the init of [TinyMCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyMCE) for Magento admin.

I'm just not satisfied with the default options and want to give my client a more user-friendly way of working with. So I want to remove some plugins, change some options and perhaps add some other plugins. But I want to keep the integrated Magento functionality.

I have not yet found a way to acomplish this without editing the `js/mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js` directly.

Is there a working solution?

---

**UPDATE**

Tobias' solution works very well! As you can read below, I had some trouble getting it to work due to `403 forbidden` errors on my localhost. On my staging server however it worked as expected.

After some more testing, I found that the `Fooman_Speedster` extension I had installed was the cause of the problem. After disabling that, everything works fine!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can esily create your own module (depends on Mage_Adminhtml) which is extending that js file:

config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Your_Module>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Your_Module>
    </modules>

    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <your_module>
                    <file>your/module.xml</file>
                </your_module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

In your layout file you add a custom js to the header:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem">
                <type>skin_js</type>
                <name>your_module/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup.js</name>
                <params/>
                <if/>
                <condition>can_load_tiny_mce</condition>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

And in the new setup.js you can overwrite the prototype object:

```
(function (getSettings) {
    tinyMceWysiwygSetup.prototype.getSettings = function (mode) {
        var oSettings = getSettings.call(this, mode);
        oSettings.extended_valid_elements = "article[class]";
        return oSettings;
    };
}(tinyMceWysiwygSetup.prototype.getSettings));
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! Looks like it's the way to go. However, when I follow your instructions, I'm getting a network error `403 forbidden` on the `/skin/m/...` url. Do you know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: what's the exact name of your file and where did you store it?

Comment: I've given it the name `application_adminhtml/tiny_mce/setup.js`. When I inspect with firebug, the file is included as `/skin/adminhtml/base/default/application_adminhtml/tiny_mce/setup.js` - which is directly reachable via browser. As content I just have an `alert('...');` statement in the file - but changing or deleting the content has no effect on the error.

Comment: Ehm there seems to be a typo or something like that. in your first comment you wrote that you get a 403 on /skin/m/ ... what's the m? in your second comment there's no m mentioned

Comment: There's no typo, but perhaps I could've been clearer. Magento aggregates multiple files into one call. The full url is quite long so I had to trim it: `https://www...com.dev/skin/m/1401549822/js/prototype/prototype.js,/js/extjs/fix-defer-before.js,/js/prototype/window.js,/js/scriptaculous/builder.js,/js/scriptaculous/effects.js,/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js,....,/skin/adminhtml/base/default/application_adminhtml/tiny_mce/setup.js`

Comment: I just found out that when I remove the `<params/><if/>
<condition>` part, the added JS *does* work on pages that do no have a editor, and I get the alert. On pages *with* the editor I get the 403 forbidden error on the javascript file.

Comment: Update: I was testing on a localhost, where it didn't work. When I test it on my staging server however, it *does* work. I guess you solution is correct and the problem is with my localhost. Thank you very much for your answer and time!!

Comment: The /skin/m/1401549822 path is likely coming from using my Speedster extension and an unrelated issue to your current question (might be permissions).